# Parallel Capacitors

Tags: components, parallel

I have a power supply with two output capacitors in parallel. 16v 2700uf.
Theoretically, couldn't they be replaced with one 16v or higher 5400uf or do they form some kind of quasi LC circuit via the copper traces?

Comment: Are you lucky or what??? Here's your answer https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wwANKw36Mjw Just saw this yesterday! Also, in my experience ESR drops with higher value caps, but they also have to be physically bigger (best way to guarantee that is higher voltage rating). I've never seen 2700 or 5400uF. 6800uF is more common, but then inrush current will change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have a power supply with two output capacitors in parallel. 16v 2700uf. Theoretically, couldn't they be replaced with one 16v or higher 5400uf

In theory yes, but the parallel caps may offer some advantages:

- Cost, stock management... Maybe the manufacturer uses the same model of caps in several products, they order a large quantity and it's cheaper for them to use either one or two rather than stocking two different caps.
- Form factor, notably capacitor height. Everything needs to be thin these days, and you don't want your flat TV's thickness to be determined by just one tall cap when two smaller ones will do the job.
- Lower ESR perhaps, depends on cost.
- Two caps have lower inductance than one cap, but inductance is very dependent on layout also.
- Two caps can dissipate more power than one, due to having more surface area in contact with air.

Answer (score 0):

I have never heard of a power supply being designed with that in mind.  However, there might be a significant difference is total ESR with two small cps vs one large one.  Also, two small caps would probably have a significantly lower total induction. Those things might or might not be important for your circuit.

Answer (score 0):

That would depend on the layout. Are the caps physically right next to each other? And are they connected by a regular short trace? If yes, they you probably *can* use one larger cap.

There will be minor differences between the two arrangements. For example the ESR, and maximum ripple will be different for 2 small caps than for 1 large one. Whether this matters depends on the circuit, but in most cases it would not have a noticeable effect.

Comment: Yes. right next to one another and straight short traces. I am thinking it may have been just for space reasons.